# VB.NET: List all project folders in a ListBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I wondered about how you can list every folder inside `root` folder in a `ListBox`

I have been searching all around google, but I didn't understand anything so it wasen't for any help at all. My current code is

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' make a reference to a directory
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\TTC\projects\")
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

    'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each dra In diar1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
    Next
End Sub
```

Imports I used was `System.IO`, `System.Collections`

Still nothing seem to work, any ideas?

**EDIT:**

The script that I made was looking for files not folders, so just change everything to Directory instead of File

Comment: you are storing a fileinfo object.  if you want the name `ListBox1.Items.Add(dra.FullName)`  or other flavor like Name  or set the .DisplayMember to the desired property

Comment: It probably also a good idea to call [`ListBox.BeginUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.beginupdate(v=vs.110).aspx) before you add items and `ListBox.EndUpdate` after you've finished adding items -- this reduces unnecessary updates of the listbox while items are still being added in the loop.

Comment: If you have the answer, you should post it as an answer to your question, rather than as an edit. Decent self-answers are very much encouraged on StackOverflow.

Comment: @MicroVirus I've been told to put the answer in an edit instead of posing it, that was on one of my different accounts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a Recursive routine. Try something like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
        FillListBox("C:\TTC\projects\")
        ListBox1.EndUpdate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillListBox(folder As String)
        Dim fi As New IO.DirectoryInfo(folder)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(fi.FullName)

        For Each f In fi.GetDirectories
            FillListBox(f.FullName)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the paths of all folders and subfolders:

```
Dim paths = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\TTC\projects\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(paths)
```

If you want to list just the folder names, try this:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\TTC\projects\").GetDirectories()
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
```